# How to remove creditional prompt that appear after deployment in sql reporting service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

When i create report using sql reporting services and deployed it on localhost/reportserver i got a prompt that should enter userName and password.. 
i want to remove this prompt .. That no more the user get it .
How I can do that ??
using that in asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have a domain and kerberos / pass through authentication set up correctly.

You could add an sql user to your database and give this sql user permission to get the report data
Then add the credentials for of this sql user to the report.